# remove elements from dynamic form

Tags: jquery, forms, element

I have this form:
http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/JrBrR/

How can I implement the remove Paragraph function in jquery?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's live method to bind to future instances of paragraphs. For each new form, you can write:

```
 $('.deleteButton').live(function(){
      $(this).siblings('p').remove();
 });
```

`live` is like `bind` but acts on any element that is added in future. :)

Comment: You're missing an `'` in your `siblings` element ;o)

Answer (score 2):

`$("p").remove()` should do the trick.  Read up more about `remove` here:

[jQuery Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)